# Android index php file does not register the user

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, sqlite

I'm currently following [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/) by Android Hive on how to create a Login and Registration system using PHP and MYSQL; however, I'm having some difficulties with registering a user.

Edit: My problem is that whenever the register button is clicked it just returns back "Required tag is missing" and does not store any data as it should.

[image: Image of LogCat when the "Register" button is clicked]

I have tried using the Advanced Rest Client extension for Google Chrome, but it didn't really provide me with any useful information.

The `index.php` file contains all the functions for storing and getting the data of the users from the database:

```
<?php
//this file has the role fo accepting requests and giving JSON responses.
// Accepts POST and GET requests


if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != ''){
    //get the tag
    $tag = $_POST['tag'];

    //include a database handler
    require_once 'login_api/DB_Functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();

    //reponse array
    $response = array("tag" => $tag, "error" => FALSE);

    //check for the tag type
    if ($tag == 'login'){
        //request type is going to be to check the login
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        //check for the user
        $user = $db->getUsersByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);
        if ($user != false){
            //this mean the user has been found
            $response["error"] = FALSE;
            $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
            $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
            $response["user"]["created"] = $user["created"];
            $response["user"]["updated"] = $user["updated"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        }else {
            //user is not found
            //echo the json with error = 1
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect email or password";
            echo json_response($response);
        }
    }else if ($tag == 'register') {
        //request type is to register a new user
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        //check to see if the user already exists
        if ($db->isUserExisted($email)){
            //user already exists so produce an error response
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "User Already Exists";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }else{
            //store user
            $user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $password);
            if ($user){
                //user is stored successfully
                //Creating the data for JSON
                $response["error"] = FALSE;
                $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
                $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
                $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
                $response["user"]["created"] = $user["created"];
                $response["user"]["updated"] = $user["updated"];
                echo json_encode($response);
            }else{
                //failure storing the user details into the database
                $response["error"] = TRUE;
                $response["error_msg"] = "An error has occured with registering..";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        }
        }else {
        //user failed to store
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Uknown 'tag', should be either login or  register";
        echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required, 'tag' is missing";
    echo json_encode($response);
    }

?>
```

My RegisterActivity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);

    // Progress dialog
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    // Session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    // SQLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if user is already logged in or not
    if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
        // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,
                MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    // Register Button Click event
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

            if (!name.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                registerUser(name, email, password);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter your details!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    });

    // Link to Login Screen
    btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Function to store user in MySQL database will post params(tag, name,
 */
private void registerUser(final String name, final String email,
                          final String password) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_register";

    pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                if (!error) {
                    // User successfully stored in MySQL
                    // Now store the user in sqlite
                    String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                    JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    String name = user.getString("name");
                    String email = user.getString("email");
                    String created = user
                            .getString("created");

                    // Inserting row in users table
                    db.addUser(name, email, uid, created);

                    // Launch login activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            RegisterActivity.this,
                            LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {

                    // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                    // message
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to register url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("tag", "register");
            params.put("name", name);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}

private void showDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hideDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

Comment: So what is your problem then?

Comment: It seems that your `getParams()` function is not getting called for some reason.

Comment: @DanielNugent Yeah im not really sure why though, ive followed the steps carefully and even downloaded his code but i cant figure out whats wrong with mine. Im not a very adept android programmer so finding the cause is a real big pain in the backside for me